# Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, apollo

I am learning GraphQL with Java and came across one basic project to know how GraphQL works. But I encountered a problem while running it. Below are the files of the project.

**Book.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public record Book (String id, String name, int pageCount, String authorId) {

    private static List<Book> books = Arrays.asList(
            new Book("book-1", "Effective Java", 416, "author-1"),
            new Book("book-2", "Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", 208, "author-2"),
            new Book("book-3", "Down Under", 436, "author-3")
    );

    public static Book getById(String id) {
        return books.stream()
                .filter(book -> book.id().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

**Author.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public record Author (String id, String firstName, String lastName) {

    private static List<Author> authors = Arrays.asList(
            new Author("author-1", "Joshua", "Bloch"),
            new Author("author-2", "Douglas", "Adams"),
            new Author("author-3", "Bill", "Bryson")
    );

    public static Author getById(String id) {
        return authors.stream()
                .filter(author -> author.id().equals(id))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

**BookController.java**

```
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.Argument;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.QueryMapping;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.SchemaMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class BookController {
    @QueryMapping
    public Book bookById(@Argument String id) {
        return Book.getById(id);
    }

    @SchemaMapping
    public Author author(Book book) {
        return Author.getById(book.authorId());
    }
}
```

**schema.graphqls**

```
type Query {
    bookById(id: ID): Book
}

type Book {
    id: ID
    name: String
    pageCount: INT
    author: Author
}

type Author {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
}
```

**Project Structure:**
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdshG.png)

**application.properties**
`spring.application.name=springGraphQL spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled=true`

**Dependencies**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.surbhi</groupId>
    <artifactId>springGraphQL</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springGraphQL</name>
    <description>GraphQL project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Error**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2m2024-03-28T19:20:55.582+05:30[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m10896[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[springGraphQL] [           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'routerFunctionMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlRouterFunction' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlRouterFunction' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlHttpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlHttpHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'executionGraphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'executionGraphQlService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception with message: errors=[The field type 'INT' is not present when resolving type 'Book' [@5:1]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:962) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at com.surbhi.springGraphQL.SpringGraphQlApplication.main(SpringGraphQlApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlRouterFunction' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlRouterFunction' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlHttpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlHttpHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'executionGraphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'executionGraphQlService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception with message: errors=[The field type 'INT' is not present when resolving type 'Book' [@5:1]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$1.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:473) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping.initRouterFunctions(RouterFunctionMapping.java:152) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.function.support.RouterFunctionMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RouterFunctionMapping.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlHttpHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQlHttpHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'webGraphQlHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/servlet/GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webGraphQlHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'executionGraphQlService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'executionGraphQlService' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'graphQlSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource]: Factory method 'graphQlSource' threw exception with message: errors=[The field type 'INT' is not present when resolving type 'Book' [@5:1]]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:542) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1165) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:904) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782) ~[spring-beans-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

Comment: @Mini you need to include the text, not images of the text.  BTW, that stack trace probably tells you exactly why it's failing, but it's impossible to say without setting the full text.  Read up on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Mini The stack trace indicates `The field type 'INT' is not present...`.  I don't believe that `INT` is a valid type, but `Int` is.  In your schema, change the type of pageCount from INT to Int.